# Pass data between two controllers but not via url as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

below is my code

```
<% if @user.empty? == true %>
  <p> Sorry no data to display</p>
<%else%>
  <% @user.each do |n|%>
   User id = <%=n.id%> <br \>
   User type = <%=n.type%> <br \>
   User name = <%= n.name%> <br \>
   <%= link_to "Good. You can proceed on creating a new", new_user_product_path(current_user)%>
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

This code is currently under `searches#index`. Now as you can see,  after a set of results is shown, I want the user to be able to create a new product. But when creating the product, I want to make sure `<%= n.name%>` is pass over to `new_user_product_path(current_user)` (its a form). But not via url.

The form field which i want to populate is

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_name%>
```

So, how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You should make a custom form_tag (POST method) with the link_to becoming a submit button, with a hidden_field_tag containing the value `n.name`

Comment: i am not understanding, could you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass name from search index, as you have current user reference:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_name, current_user.name %>
```

This will render a hidden input with a value of current user name.

Even you don't need this parameter to be passed after user submits form.

If you are doing this I suppose is to have the user name reference available in client, to do something like this in Javascript:

```
alert($('[ name = user_name ]').val());
```

Comment: I cant do this, because not current_user.name is not what i want. `n.name` is not the same as current_user.name :)

Comment: but than you have to change your new_user_product_path(current_user) to new_user_product_path(n)..i think.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a solution

I just made `<%=n.name%>` to `<% $name = n.name %>` and since a global variable, its accessible now.